# How to combine subplots with a plot with two y-axes in plotly?

Tags: r, plotly

I want to have two subplots, same x-axis. In the top plot, I want to have two y-axes. If I only show `top`, both plots are correctly displayed. But in `both`, the plot from df2 is missing. Why and how can I fix it?

```
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- data.frame(t=seq(5)) %>% mutate(d1=t+7)
df2 <- data.frame(t=seq(2,6)) %>% mutate(d2=t*t+20)
df3 <- data.frame(t=seq(0,8)) %>% mutate(d3=-2-t)

top <- plot_ly() %>%
  add_trace(x=~t,y=~d1,type="scatter",data=df1,mode="lines") %>%
  add_trace(x=~t,y=~d2,type="scatter",data=df2,mode="lines",yaxis = "y2") %>%
  layout(yaxis2 = list(overlaying = "y", side = "right"))
bottom <- plot_ly() %>%
  add_trace(x=~t,y=~d3,type="scatter",data=df3,mode="lines")
both <- list(top ,bottom ) %>% subplot(nrows=2,shareX=T)
```

I tried to understand a similar question asked for Python, but I don't see how it relates to my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the plot with dual axis you should change the `layout` of `yaxis` to left side which is your first axis, yaxis2 to right as second yaxis and with the "overlaying" argument to "y". Here is a reproducible example:

```r
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

df1 <- data.frame(t=seq(5)) %>% mutate(d1=t+7)
df2 <- data.frame(t=seq(2,6)) %>% mutate(d2=t*t+20)
df3 <- data.frame(t=seq(0,8)) %>% mutate(d3=-2-t)

top <- plot_ly() %>%
  add_trace(x=~t,y=~d1,type="scatter",data=df1,mode="lines") %>%
  add_trace(x=~t,y=~d2,type="scatter",data=df2,mode="lines",yaxis = "y2") %>%
  layout(yaxis=list(side="left"),
         yaxis2=list(side="right",overlaying="y"))
bottom <- plot_ly() %>%
  add_trace(x=~t,y=~d3,type="scatter",data=df3,mode="lines")
subplot(top, bottom, nrows = 2, shareX = TRUE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you know where in the documentation I can find info like this? Should I look for doc of python-plotly or directly for R-plotly? What's your suggestion?